# Why is this Controller code able to Create one node but not Edit the other one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

In my Rails app, there are nodes which can point to each other by filling in the id of their previous_node_id and next_node_id columns. When I create a node, it successfully points back to the previous node, but the previous node does not change and its next_node_id value remains nil. How do I fix this? (I'll also appreciate any comments about how to improve the code.)

NodesController:

```
def create
@node = current_user.nodes.build(params[:node])

if params[:previous_node_id].present?
setup_node_pointers(Node.find(params[:previous_node_id]), @node ) 
end

if @node.save
...//end of the controller
```

Relevant code from the Helper:

```
def setup_node_pointers(previous_node, current_node)
    previous_node.next_node_id = current_node.id
    current_node.previous_node_id = previous_node.id
    previous_node.save 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `current_node.id` is nil.  The `build` command doesn't save the record to the db so there's no `id` assigned to `@node`.  Save `@node` before your call to the helper and it should work.  If you need to bypass validations to save it, do `@node.save(validate: false)`

Comment: Thanks, but even after putting the save before, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user29358 I don't see what else could be the problem.  Maybe your saves are failing?  Show me the errors you're getting and what your models look like.  Also, try working in your console if you haven't and call the helper to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Its surprising how many errors there were in so little code!

1. Need to save current node 1st (see Steve's answer)
2. :previous_node_id was part of the node params, so it should have been
   `params[:node][:previous_node_id]`
3. cannot call helper from controller. the current_node was setup in the initial build, so
4. some of the helper code was redundant, causing confusion.

Comment: nice, should've seen #3 sry i missed it